# ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.getMessage() doesn't use the arguments I give it

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I'm using `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` to support multi-languages.

I'm not able to "send" to `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.getMessage()` the arguments to "build" the message.

The message that I get on the screen is `the fields are {0} and {1}`, but I expected to see `the fields are name and surname`

IMPORTANT: In my scenario I can't use `spring:message`, I have to programmatically print the messages.

This is the bean defined in .xml file:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>WEB-INF/I18n/dao/dao</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
       <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/> 
</bean>
```

This is the class where I call `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.getMessage()`

```
public class I18nMessageHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    public String printMessage() {
        ...             
        return messageSource.getMessage("messageA", new Object[] { "name", "surname" }, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        ...    
    }
}
```

This is the controller, where I call `I18nMessageHandler.printMessage()`

```
@Controller
public class indexController {

    @Autowired
    private I18nMessageHandler i18nMessageHandler;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {                
        model.addAttribute("message",  i18nMessageHandler.printMessage());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

this is the jsp page

```
${message}
```

This is the file properties:

```
messageA = the fields are {0} and {1}
```

Can you spot my error?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually using `printMessage`? Also you should use `MessageSource` and not the concrete type (not related but you should be programming to interfaces).

Comment: @M.Deinum  printMessage is just a name of a method of my class. It has nothing to do with ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource  methods.
I'm not getting what you are saying :(

Comment: Yes but this method is using the properties, are you using this method to print the message? How are you obtaining the message. I you have the `printMessage` method and you never use it then how do you expect that the properties are going to be passed ?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have another class where I call I18nMessageHandler.printMessage(). By calling I18nMessageHandler.printMessage() I get on the jsp page  **"the fields are {0} and {1}"** . I'm not sure I'm understading what you are telling me.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. Post the relevant code, you only posted a snippet, but not where you use that method. Add the jsp. Also when using Spring why are you even calling that method from your jsp... You should be using the spring `message` tag... i.e something like `<spring:message code="messageA" arguments="name,surname' />`. You shouldn't be calling methods from a JSP.

Comment: @MDP never mind - you edited it away. If I had your problem, I'd add some Log statement right before the return in printMessage and log the message once before passing it back. Just to make sure the parameters are acutally there and not null or something unexpected (like ("{0}" and "{1}")

Comment: Sorry everybody, maybe i wasn't clear. I edited my post. Anyway, I can't use spring:message since I have to manipulate the message before printing it to screen. I don't get any error, everything seems to work, but the issue that the args i pass to getMessage() are not printed in the message

Comment: And why wouldn't you be able to modify the message using the message tag? You can pass arguments as well ... Maybe you should first start understanding the message resolution and printing mechanism before you start working around it...